# Norm of power of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider operator norm (or 2-norm) and any square real matrix $A$ with $\rho(A)<1$, is the following statement true, and how can we prove it?

Given two positive integers $k_1$, $k_2$ such that $k_1 > k_2$, it holds that
$$
\|A^{k_1}\| < \|A^{k_2} \|.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. As an example, consider
$$
A = 0.9 \cdot \pmatrix{1 & 10\\0 & 1}.
$$
We find that $\|A^{k_1}\| > \|A^{k_2}\|$ for all $0 < k_2 < k_1 \leq 9$. In particular, we have
$$
\|A^k\| = 0.9^{k} \cdot \sqrt{50 k^{2} + 10 k \sqrt{25 k^{2} + 1} + 1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is “no”, because $\|A\|$ can be greater than $1$ even if $\rho(A)<1$. E.g. let $a>1$ and
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&a&0\\ 0&0&a\\ 0&0&0}.
$$
Then $\rho(A)=0<1$ but $\|A\|=a<a^2=\|A^2\|$.

However, for any matrix $A$ with $\rho(A)<1$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n=0$. So, given any fixed $N$ such that $A^N\ne0$, eventually we must have $\|A^n\|<\|A^N\|$ when $n$ is sufficiently large.